# override func viewDidLoad

Tags: swift, overriding, declaration

**how can I fix this? tells me that viewDidLoad was declared 2 times but as I can unify the whole process ?**

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI
import CoreData
import MediaPlayer
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "Media picker..."

        buttonPickAndPlay = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as? UIButton

        if let pickAndPlay = buttonPickAndPlay{
            pickAndPlay.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 37)
            pickAndPlay.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.center.y - 50)
            pickAndPlay.setTitle("Pick and Play", forState: .Normal)
            pickAndPlay.addTarget(self,
                action: "displayMediaPickerAndPlayItem",
                forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            view.addSubview(pickAndPlay)
        }

        buttonStopPlaying = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as? UIButton

        if let stopPlaying = buttonStopPlaying{
            stopPlaying.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 37)
            stopPlaying.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.center.y + 50)
            stopPlaying.setTitle("Stop Playing", forState: .Normal)
            stopPlaying.addTarget(self,
                action: "stopPlayingAudio",
                forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            view.addSubview(stopPlaying)
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var Subject: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet weak var Body: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        searchBar?.delegate = self

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

        webView?.scalesPageToFit = true
        webView?.loadRequest(request)

    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the body of one of the two into the other one, except for this line `super.viewDidLoad()`, which must be called once:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "Media picker..."

    buttonPickAndPlay = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as? UIButton

    if let pickAndPlay = buttonPickAndPlay{
        pickAndPlay.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 37)
        pickAndPlay.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.center.y - 50)
        pickAndPlay.setTitle("Pick and Play", forState: .Normal)
        pickAndPlay.addTarget(self,
            action: "displayMediaPickerAndPlayItem",
            forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(pickAndPlay)
    }

    buttonStopPlaying = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as? UIButton

    if let stopPlaying = buttonStopPlaying{
        stopPlaying.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 37)
        stopPlaying.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.center.y + 50)
        stopPlaying.setTitle("Stop Playing", forState: .Normal)
        stopPlaying.addTarget(self,
            action: "stopPlayingAudio",
            forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(stopPlaying)
    }

    ///

    searchBar?.delegate = self

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    webView?.scalesPageToFit = true
    webView?.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Just curios, why did you declare that method twice?

Comment: Perfect! Works great ! Thanks Antonio ! I declare That method twice because I'm a newbie !! He thinks that the two buttons ( buttonPickAndPlay and buttonStopPlaying ) should be only in viewController3 and instead I find them in all my viewController !!!!! I have to solve this problem !! Thanks for your help and fast for your attention!